# Ember re render component

Tags: ember.js

I have a component with a jquery menu that transforms the DOM. I need to re render the component for initiate the structure again. The jquery menu doesn't  work dinamically, so I need to re render the component.

```
//Parent Component hbs
<div id="container">
    {{menu-jquery model=model}}
</div>

//Parent Component js
export default Ember.Component.extend({

   refreshMenuData(){
      callToServer()// ajax call
      updateModel()// generate model from ajax response

      -> //how to delete and create menu component? or re render menu component?
   }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround putting the component inside a conditional block. I set loading in false before the server call and true after data parsing.

```
{{#if loading}}
  // show loading message
{{else}}
  {{menu-jquery model=model}}
{{/if}}
```

This force the menu component to re render.

Answer (score 2):

A component has a function called `rerender`that you can call to force a `rerender` of the component. Although, I might recommend a better approach. Upon resolution of the promise that fetches your server data, manually destroy the jquery plugin and then reinit said plugin.

Comment: Thanks, how I get a component reference in code to call renderer method?

Comment: Calling rerender doesn't change anything, i found a workaround putting the component inside {{#unless loading}} block and setting loading true before the server call. This force the menu component to re render.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear. I am assuming that, you will be using jquery ajax for server calls inside the component. In [Ember.Component](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html), you have to use *.on("didInsertElement")* which works similarly as that of *jQuery(document).ready()*. So your component will look something like this

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    _onReady: function() {
        refreshMenuData();
        //whatever jquery code you want to execute here
    }.on('didInsertElement')
})
```

If you can provide your example in Ember Twiddle or JSBin, I can help you better.

Comment: Sorry, I found that the problem is a konw issue of the jquery plugin, so I need to delete and create the entire component.