# Re render a component from another component Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to re-render a specific `component` when another `component` is clicked. When the user clicks the particular `button component`, a variable in `sessionStorage` changes, which is used by another `component` to display data. Upon click I want that specific component to re-render itself. I have seen [Ember Re-render component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318767/ember-re-render-component) and [Ember Rerendering component within component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945879/re-rendering-a-component-within-another-component), but they don't seem to be working in my case. Here are my files:

**templates/components/buttons/button-cancel.hbs**

```
{{#each-in metaData as |module definition|}}
  {{#if (eq definition.name "cancel_button") }}
  <button class={{definition.css_class}} {{action "changeToAccounts"}}> Accounts </button>
  {{/if}}
{{/each-in}}
{{yield}}
```

**components/buttons/button-cancel.js**

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import MD from "../../utils/metadata";

export default Component.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.metaData = MD.create().getMetaViewStuff("Leads", "record", "buttons");
    //    console.log(this.metaData);
  },
  actions: {
    changeToAccounts: function() {
      sessionStorage.setItem('module', "Accounts");
    }
  }

});
```

**templates/components/panels/list-panel.hbs**

```
{{buttons/button-save}} <!--This button is same as button-cancel-->
{{buttons/button-cancel}}
{{field-list-headers}}
{{yield}}
```

**components/field-list-headers** (the component that needs re-rendering)

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import MD from "../utils/metadata"

export default Component.extend({
  init: function(){
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.metaData = MD.create().getMetaViewStuff(sessionStorage.getItem('module'), "list", "panels")
  }
});
```

**function getMetaViewStuff**

```
  getMetaViewStuff: function(module, submodule, item, i18n) {
    if (this.modules[module]["views"][submodule]["meta"] !== undefined && this.modules[module]["views"][submodule]["meta"][item] !== undefined) {
      let meta = this.modules[module]["views"][submodule]["meta"][item];
      return meta;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to share the same property via a service and to use this service to update local storage and cache the value on said service. I've provided an [example](https://ember-twiddle.com/fc955f8d5d594cac0709c8d91f41a5ae?openFiles=services.mode-service.js%2C) that uses a service to share a value amongst two components (I couldn't use local storage in the twiddle).

So let's assume we want to show a list of programming languages either as a table or as an ordered list. We have two components, the reusable `mode-changer` button for toggling the mode and the `programming-languages` component for actually rendering the list, who both interact with the shared `mode-service`.:

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  init(){
    this._super(...arguments);
    //actually read from local storage here and set default on null
    this.set('mode', 'list');
  },
  toggleMode(){
    let newValue = this.get('mode') === 'list' ? 'table' : 'list';
    //actually store to local storage here before caching on the service
    this.set('mode', newValue);  
  }
});
```

Imagine this template showing both components:

```
{{programming-languages languages=languages}}
{{mode-changer}}
```

The `mode-changer` injects the `mode-service`, with which it derives the logical button text and toggle the `mode-service`'s `mode` property via `toggleMode`:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  modeService: inject(),
  buttonText: computed('modeService.mode', function(){
    let mode = this.get('modeService.mode');
    return mode === 'list' ? "Change to table" : "Change to list";
  }),
  actions: {
    toggleMode(){
      let modeService = this.get('modeService');
      modeService.toggleMode();
    }
  }
});
```

component of `mode-changer`:

```
<button onclick={{action 'toggleMode'}}>{{buttonText}}</button>
```

The `programming-languages` component bases it's rendering mode off of `modeService.mode` via a computed property:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  modeService: inject(),
  renderList: computed('modeService.mode', function(){
    let mode = this.get('modeService.mode');
    return mode === 'list';
  })
});
```

so that changes to the `modeService.mode` will cause the computed property to invalidate and trigger a render of the component.

```
{{#if renderList}}
    <ol>
  {{#each languages as |language|}}
    <li>{{language}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ol>
{{else}}
  <table>
    <th>Language</th>
      {{#each languages as |language|}}
      <tr>{{language}}</tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>
{{/if}}
```

In Ember, service's are singletons so such sharing is appropriate in many cases. To me, this is much better than any other solution that actually stores/retrieves references to the component itself and invokes its render function.